# Avoid textarea content overlapping with overlay box at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an overlay box at the bottom of a `textarea`. Positioning the overlay box was easy, but now I want the `textarea` content to never overlap the overlay box.

My first approach was adding `padding-bottom` so that the text never reaches the bottom of the `textarea`, where the overlay box is placed. However, as I type, the text will go under it. Also, scrolling up will cause the same undesired behavior.

Edit:

In response to some of the answers that partially solve my issue. I'm trying to make the textarea look as native as possible, so border color changing on focus would be necessary as well.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  resize: none; 
}

texarea.with-padding {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea name="" id="">I want this to never go under the red box.</textarea>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <textarea class="with-padding" name="" id="">I tried with padding-bottom, but it doesn't work either.</textarea>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Set to border none the textarea and add border to container for fake textarea border.

Comment: Using slightly larger padding than the bottom bar yields: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOYVEJ -- is this what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this riddle thanks to Saurav Rastogi's and eyetea's answers. Both were almost perfect, but failed to make the `textarea` have its border highlighted on focus. I've managed to keep this behavior using `outline`.

I think both approaches are useful as they allow for two different border highlight on focus. One leaving the overlay outside, using a `div` wrapper strategy, and the one leaving it inside, using a very thick `border-bottom`.

```css
/* Inner border on focus solution */

.textarea-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
}

.textarea-wrapper textarea {
  display: block;
  border: none;
}

.textarea-wrapper textarea:focus {
  outline: 1px solid green;
  outline-offset: 0;
}

.textarea-wrapper .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

/* Outer border on focus solution */

textarea.bottom-padded {
    border-bottom: 21px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    outline: 1px solid gray;
    outline-offset: -1px;
}

textarea.bottom-padded:focus {
    outline-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea-wrapper">
  <textarea rows="3">Inner border on focus</textarea>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<textarea rows="3" class="bottom-padded">Outer border on focus</textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `<div>` container (which holds your textarea and overlay) as a fake border and remove the border of `textarea`. Just as shown in the snippet below:

```js
$('textarea').on('focus', function() {
  $('.textarea-holder').css('border-color', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)');
});

$('textarea').on('blur', function() {
  $('.textarea-holder').css('border-color', '#333');
});
```

```css
.textarea-holder {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: inline-block;
}

.textarea-holder textarea {
  display: block;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
}

textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.textarea-holder .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textarea-holder">
  <textarea rows="6"></textarea>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! It's almost perfect, but this solution fails to highlight the border on focus.

Comment: @OmeGak Oh! my bad. I've updated this above into my code, please have a look. I've handled `:focus` using jQuery. Hope this helps!

Comment: I finally managed to find a CSS-only solution by hacking a bit `outline`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a `bottom-border: 1em` to the `textarea` to imitate the `span` element.
Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woKyvy#anon-login

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1em solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea>Try typing. The cursor will never end up under the red line.</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I went ahead and wrote it down:

1. Removed the `border` and reset some styles of `textarea`
2. Added the *fake* border to the `container` and removed the positioning of the `span` and made it a `block` element.

See code below:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  resize: none;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  padding: 0;
}

.container span {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea name="" id="">I want this to never go under the red box.</textarea>
  <span></span>
</div>
```